# How to extract values from an event in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Within Vue.js I am firing an event like this:

```js
this.$emit("change", this.data);
```

The parent receives that data and every time the event is an object. But the event consists of values and an observer. For example:

```js
{
  data: ['Joe Doe'],
  __ob__: Observer
}
```

How can I just keep grabbing all the values from an object and skip the `__ob__` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that an event is an object with `data` key, the payload can be accessed as `event.data`.

`__ob__` is non-enumerable property used by Vue reactivity, it's displayed in dimmed color in console output:

[image: ob]

Non-enumerable keys are commonly ignored when object keys are indirectly accessed - `for..in`, `Object.key`, `JSON.stringify`, etc.  `__ob__` doesn't affect the way reactive object is used, unless the property is directly accessed, which shouldn't be done without valid reasons.

Comment: Can you clarify? If `this.data` is an object with `data`, and you need event listener to receive `data` only, it could be `this.$emit("change", this.data.data)`. But this isn't related to `__ob__`, this key doesn't affect anything.

Comment: It makes sense now... I got confused the first time round due to storing incorrectly formatted event, due to which my tries using `Object` didn't work.